# How to put radio button with a php value

Tags: php, html

I am currently having a trouble using the radio button, I'm getting confuse because of the output of my codes. In the left picture that's what my output like, in the right picture I want my output like that. When I choose from the candidates both radio button can choose instead of only one should be can be chosen.

Here's my code:

```
   <?php
 $YearNow=Date('Y');
 $dsds=$rowasa['posid'];
 $results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates,student,school_year,partylist where student.idno = candidates.idno AND school_year.syearid = candidates.syearid AND posid =:a AND candidates.partyid = partylist.partyid AND  school_year.from_year like $YearNow  ");

                $results->bindParam(':a', $dsds);
                $results->execute();
                for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){
                ?>
        //here's the part that i was confuse    


    <input type ="radio"><input style="padding: 35px 50px 35px 80px; background:url('admin/candidates/images/<?php echo $rows['image']; ?>')  no-repeat scroll 5px 7px / 70px auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"  
    value="<?php echo $rows['candid'] . "-" ."&nbsp". $rows['lastname'] .",". "&nbsp". $rows['firstname'] ?>"><?php echo $rows['lastname'] ?>,
                        <?php echo $rows['firstname'] ?>

                    - <?php 
                            echo $rows['party_name']?>
                        <?php

                }

            ?>
```

[image: An example image]

Comment: Set the name attribute on the radio input the same on all radio buttions and you'll only be able to select 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you SQL query is giving you the right results however I would really look into using `JOINs`. Regardless, im assuming your SQL results are something like this:

```
$candidates = array(
    array(
        "id" => "1",
        "firstname" => "John",
        "image" => "some/image/path",
        "party_name" => "Party1",
    ),
    array(
        "id" => "2",
        "firstname" => "Jane",
        "image" => "some/image/path",
        "party_name" => "Party2",
    )
);
```

To iterate through this and build your HTML, it will be a lot easier to use `foreach` like so:

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
    <?php
    foreach ($candidates as $candidate) {
        ?>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="admin/candidates/images/<?php echo $candidate['image']; ?>" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <input type="radio" name="candidate_selected" value="<?= $candidate['id'] ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <?php echo $candidate['firstname'] . " - " . $candidate['party_name'] ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Notice how the `input` has the same name and the `id` of your candidate results. Once this is submitted, you should only see the `id` of the selected candidate in your `submit.php` handler.

Now add some CSS:

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.box .image {
    padding: 15px;
}

.box .image img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try echo the radio button like this.

```
 <?php
 $YearNow=Date('Y');
 $dsds=$rowasa['posid'];
 $results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates,student,school_year,partylist where student.idno = candidates.idno AND school_year.syearid = candidates.syearid AND posid =:a AND candidates.partyid = partylist.partyid AND  school_year.from_year like $YearNow  ");

                $results->bindParam(':a', $dsds);
                $results->execute();
                for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){

        //here's the part that i was confuse    


    echo "<input type ='radio'><input style='padding: 35px 50px 35px 80px; background:url('admin/candidates/images/". $rows['image'] . "')  no-repeat scroll 5px 7px / 70px auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);  
    value='" . $rows['candid'] . " - "$rows['lastname'] ", ". $rows['firstname'] . "'>" . $rows['lastname'] . "," . $rows['firstname'];
echo $rows['firstname'] ." - ". $rows['party_name'];


                }

            ?>
```